# How to load variables to the views in more than 1 routes in laravel

Tags: laravel, routes, view, laravel-5.4

I am using laravel 5.4 and I have an admin panel which has many routes and the application itself has many routes.

For all the admin panel routes, I needed a variable to load on every views of the admin so I used a service provider and returning that variable to the view like this.

```
view()->composer('*', function ($view)
    {
        /*total unseen contacts*/
            $contact= DB::table('contacts')
                 ->select(DB::raw('count(status) as cont'))
                 ->where('status', '=', 0)
                 ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                 ->get();

        $view->with('contact', $contact);
    });
```

and this works fine but the problem is this query also runs in the main application where there is no need for this query at all.

So the question is how can I separate admin routes and application routes? Please let me know if there are any other better ways to do so.

Thank you.

Comment: Route groups are probably where you are wanting to look.
[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-groups)

Comment: Change your view()->composer(' * ') to view()->composer('admin. * ')

Comment: Thank you! It should be an answer buddy. It worked and you know it solved another problem which is, I saw the service provider was getting run multiple times unnecessarily but now runs once and only admin routes. Thank you.

Comment: use middlewares!